# Is it possible to keep a div position fixed while scrolling but keep it left aligned with container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fixed

I have a div that I would like in a fixed position while the user scrolls up and down but I would like it to maintain its left alignment to match all the other divs within a container. I am using Bootstrap 3 and have all my divs in a container. I want one div to stay in one spot as the user scrolls up and down however I want it to keep the left alignment inherited by the .container from bootstrap so it still aligns with everything else on the site. This is what I have so far to no avail. It doesn't follow the rest of the div's alignment.

```
#section {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  z-index: -10;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
}

<div id="section" class="parallax-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h1>Transformative</h1>
            <h1>thinking.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the `left:10%`

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `left:10%` line.

I have found the error through using http://codepen.io/pen/ May be a useful tool to use for future css designing/debugging.

Comment: The link seems broken